# On button click, Increment the count starting from 0 and if the count is multiple of 3 then skip and show the next number in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mern

I want to display the counts starting from default 0 value and on click of button it should increment the count and show the value but if the current count is multiple of 3 then skip the value and show the next value instead. For ex. -> It should be showing in this occurrence **0,1,2,4,5,7,8,10,11,13,14,16...** on button click.

Here is the code I've written ->

```
import React, {useState} from "react";

export default function App() {
  // increment the count by 1 but
  // skip the values which are multiplier of 3
  // Eg: 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11, 13...

  const[count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const changeCounter = async () => {        //Tried Async await here
    console.log('here is count -> ', count)  //Always print one value behind.
    if(count === 0){
      setCount(count + 1);
    }
    else if(count % 3 === 0){
      setCount(count+2);
    }
    else {
      setCount(count+1);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello People</h1>
      <p>Count: {count}
      </p>
      <button onClick= {() => changeCounter()}>Click me!</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

But i am experiencing something strange here, Instead of skipping multiple of 3 It skips the next value of it. For ex. It is showing as -> **0,1,2,3,5,6,8,9,11...** like this.

Even I tried async, await, setTimeout and setCount(c => c+1) so that it will reflect once the setCount will update the value properly but still nothing worked.

I know that the console value always print behind but why it is affecting the UI part? It should not be working like this. What is the reason behind this and how can we overcome this issue?

Comment: Assume `count` currently has the value `3`. Then `else if(count % 3 === 0)`will be true, so you are calling `setCount(count+2)`. So of course that results in `5` ...

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that you are checking if the number is dividable by three before skipping, that's why instead it's skipping the number after it.

So what you need to do is check if the number that comes after the current number is dividable by 3:

```
  const changeCounter = () => {
    console.log('here is count -> ', count)
    if((count + 1) === 0){
      setCount(prev => prev + 1);
    }
    else if((count + 1) % 3 === 0){
      setCount(prev => prev + 2);
    }
    else {
      setCount(prev => prev + 1);
    }
  }
```